# python-daemon doesn't call the start function

Tags: python, debian, python-daemon

I've been following the [this example](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#example-usage) to implement a python daemon, and it seems to be somewhat working, but only the reconfigure function is called.

This is the code I've been using:

```
import signal
import daemon
import lockfile

import manager

context = daemon.DaemonContext(
    working_directory='/home/debian/station',
    pidfile=lockfile.FileLock('/var/run/station.pid'))

context.signal_map = {
    signal.SIGTERM: manager.Manager.program_terminate,
    signal.SIGHUP: 'terminate',
    signal.SIGUSR1: manager.Manager.program_reload_configuration,
    }

manager.Manager.program_configure()

with context:
    manager.Manager.program_start()
```

This is the code on the manager class:

```
@staticmethod
def program_configure():
    logging.info('Configuring program')

@staticmethod
def program_reload_configuration():
    logging.info('Reloading configuration')

@staticmethod
def program_start():
    global Instance
    logging.info('Program started')
    Instance = Manager()
    Instance.run()

@staticmethod
def program_terminate():
    logging.info('Terminating')
```

And the log shows only:

```
INFO:root:Configuring program
```

For some reason `program_start()` isn't being called. 
`program_configure()` is called every time the python file is read, so that's that, but why isn't `program_start()` called?

I start the daemon by typing `sudo service station.sh start` and the line that runs the script is:

```
python $DAEMON start
```

EDIT:
After reading a bit, I've realized that the program probably exits or hangs in `context.__enter__()` (`with` calls that). But I have no clue what is causing this

Comment: on your terminate, you are calling the fn: you have the set of parens () instead of just giving the address (in your signal map setup)

Comment: You're right! fixed that, and edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't in the python-daemon not calling the functions, it's the logging that didn't work.

When the daemon creates a new process it doesn't transfer all file handles from the mother process - Therefore the logs aren't written. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180720/maintaining-logging-and-or-stdout-stderr-in-python-daemon) for more info.

The solution to that is to use the `files_preserve` property like so:

```
# Set the logger
LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
fh = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# Not create the context, and notify it to preserve the log file
context = daemon.DaemonContext(
    working_directory='/home/debian/station',
    pidfile=lockfile.FileLock('/var/run/station.pid'),
    files_preserve=[fh.stream],
)
```